# How to solve CORS error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, cors

I have developed a MERN stack project which needs OAuth token from facebook. In order to get the access code from facebook, I am calling the backend api `getAccessCode`. Below is my api impementation,

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const router = require('express').Router();
const {FB} = require('fb')
const QueryString = require('query-string')
const app = express();
const env = require('dotenv').config()
const constants = require('../common/constants')

const cors = require('cors')

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.use(cors())
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
});

router.route('/getAccessCode').post((request, response)=> {

    const stringifiedParams = QueryString.stringify({
        client_id : process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        redirect_uri : process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
        scope : [constants.EMAIL, constants.USER_PHOTOS],
        response_type : constants.CODE,
        auth_type : constants.RE_REQUEST,
        display : constants.POPUP
    })

    const fbURL = process.env.ACCESS_CODE_URL + stringifiedParams


    return response.redirect(fbURL)
})
```

By following several similar questions, I have found that I need to enable `CORS`. Therefore, I enabled the cors policy as in the above code. But still when I send a post request from my frontend, it gives the following error,

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.facebook.com/v11.0/dialog/oauth?auth_type=rerequest&client_id=111111111111111&display=popup&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F&response_type=code&scope=email&scope=user_photos' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8000/fb/getAccessCode') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
www.facebook.com/v11.0/dialog/oauth?auth_type=rerequest&client_id=11111111111111111&display=popup&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F&response_type=code&scope=email&scope=user_photos:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)
```

Below is my request which is written in frontend,

```
axios.post("http://localhost:8000/getAccessCode")
```

Can someone please help me to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh, is there any solution? @jabaa

Comment: i'd assume given the error you aren't following the documentation for the api you're interacting with correctly. (a redirect as a response to an ajax request isn't actually a browser redirect.) The redirect would need to be done as a response to a non-ajax post request, or done on the client.

Comment: I just append those parameters to the oauth url of facebook. Is it wrong? @KevinB

Comment: The wrong bit here is how/when/where you are redirecting. Redirecting as the response to an ajax request doesn't cause the browser to do what you need it to do.

Comment: So do I have to redirect to this url from the client side? @KevinB

Comment: client side, or just don't use ajax for this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On frontend you're making a request with `axios`. `axios` makes the request under the hood, i.e. your browser's Location header is not set. So when you redirect the request, it turns into a cross-site request, because you're still on the same domain as you were before, while trying to request data from facebook via javascript.

What you can do is either:

1. Not use axios request to fetch the URL, you can build the URL in the frontend and navigate user to that URL (with `<a href=` or a button or programmatically, whatever you prefer).

*OR*

2. If you must fetch the URL string from backend, then just do that, nothing more. No need to redirect the request from the backend. So in your code, express should return `res.status(200).json({ fbURL });`. And in your axios's response handler, you should programmatically navigate the user to the facebook page for authentication: `window.location = res.data.fbURL;`

Comment: window.location thing worked. Thanks for the help!